# Переклад "heap property" для покажчика

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, словосполучення

Покажчик оригіналу серед інших містить такі елементи:

> - heap
> - heap property
> - heap ordering

відповідно всі ці елементі ідуть поруч і це зручно. Якщо перекласти як:

> - купа
> - властивість купи
> - впорядкування купи

то логічно пов'язані елементи розносяться на декілька сторінок, що незручно для читача. Поки що робимо так:

[image: поточний варіант]

Варіанти з комою: *властивість, купи* і *впорядкування купи* мають таку ваду, що в елементі покажчику кома зустрічається двічі і це може збивати з пантелику читача.

Які ще є варіанти з купою на початку?

Comment: Я правильно розумію, що головна проблема — алфавітне упорядкування у покажчику? Бо навіть англійською алфавітне упорядкування не завжди можливе, і для цього [умні люди видумали](http://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.0/indexterm.startofrange.html) `indexterm/primary` та `indexterm/secondary`.

Comment: @bytebuster гм.. тобто буде щось на кшталт `\index{купа/властивість!підтримка}`? Непогано.

Comment: Так. Мається на увазі, що одне діло — коли терміни містять спільне слово (e.g. купа, властивість купи, впорядкування купи) — там можна гратися порядком слів; а інше діло, коли ви повинні повʼязати терміни, які подібні за смислом, але різні семантично (e.g. тварини, коти, собаки).

Comment: Offtopic: до речі, той heap ще перекладають як [«стіс» і «піраміда»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Купа_(структура_даних)). Хоча «стіс» («стос») паралельно використовують як відповідник «[стеку](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Стек)» — тож не факт, що варто його брати (а «купа» і «піраміда», здається, недвозначні).

Comment: @Sasha Так, але бачу причин віддавати перевагу перевагу піраміді перед купою